# Is it possible for a variable to recognise that its is holding a dictionary variable and use it accordignly

Tags: python

Im making a simple game with tkinter in python 3 that includes a function I made that goes through a dictionary of sections of text everytime I click a button.

```
new_pokemon_dictionary = {
"1": "It's a new pokemon!", "2": "Are you ready to fight it?"#, "3": "3rd piece of text etc
}
text_scroll_n=0
def next_button():
    global text_scroll_n

    textbox.delete(0.0, END)
    text_scroll_n+=1  #Every time next_button run adds 1, this makes it print new part of the dictionary            

    if game_stage == 1:
        text_scroll("new_pokemon_dictionary")
    else:
        return
    textbox.insert(END, text_output)
    screen.update()
```

By clicking the next button `text_scroll_n` is increased by one and is used by the `text_scroll` function to choose a new part of the dictionary to display:

```
def text_scroll(dictionary):

    if text_scroll_n<=len(dictionary):
        print(dictionary)
        text_output = dictionary[str(text_scroll_n)] #Textbox will insert at end of next_button function
    else:
        game_stage +=1
```

However when running this, (and other parts of code such as creating the texbox not shown), I'm given the error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers` . 
 I'm assuming this is because it is trying to set `text_output` to a letter in `dictionary`, whose position in the word equals the integer that text_scroll_n is.

However when I replace the line `text_output = dictionary[str(text_scroll_n)]` in the `text_scroll` function with `text_output = new_pokemon_dictionary[str(text_scroll_n)` it works perfectly, recognising that the new_pokemon_dictrionary variable is a dictionary.

Is there anyway I can use the `text_scroll(dictionary)` throughout my code, just putting in the different dictionary variable names that I want to use as the paramater, or is the only fix to rewrite the needed code for all of the different dictionaries?

Im new to coding so sorry if any of this is sloppy.
Thanks!

Comment: `dictionary[str(text_scroll_n)]` in this `dictionary` is of type string

Comment: _However when running this, (and other parts of code such as creating the texbox not shown), I'm given the error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers` ._ **Please provide the entire error message as well as a [mcve].** _I'm assuming this is because it is trying to set text_output to a letter in dictionary, whose position in the word equals the integer that text_scroll_n is._ I don't believe so, no. Hint: look at `text_scroll_n` in that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I can tell, what's really going on is that you're passing the string `"new_pokemon_dictionary"` to the `text_scroll` function, instead of the dictionary `new_pokemon_dictionary`. Drop the quotes on every `text_scroll` call and you should be fine.

So this...

```
if game_stage == 1:
        text_scroll("new_pokemon_dictionary")
```

...becomes this

```
if game_stage == 1:
        text_scroll(new_pokemon_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the code to pick the right dictionary based on the string passed, which is supposed to be the name of dictionary?

You can implement a function that returns the dictionary based on name and then use it. Following code will work for you -

```
dict_1={"name":"dict_1"}
dict_2={"name":"dict_2"}

def get_dict(name):
    import sys
    return sys.modules[__name__].__dict__[name]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_dict("dict_1"))
    print(get_dict("dict_2"))
```

In your code, you can use this in following way -

```
text_scroll(get_dict("new_pokemon_dictionary"))
```